# Offset javascript scroll: cannot read property 'top' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, undefined, offset

I'm trying to use this javascript to set a sidebar nav to be offset and become sticky with scroll. The error is:

**"cannot read property 'top' of undefined"**

The error is at `var stickyNavTop = $('.toc').offset().top - 222;` and it is preventing other js to work properly.

[Example page using script](http://bit.ly/1v4W2Zn)

Script:

```
// Sidebar Nav Sticky with Scroll
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var stickyNavTop = $('.toc').offset().top - 222;
    var stickyEnd = $('.content').height() - 111; // stores height of .content element
    var praiseH = $('.praise').height(); //height of praise bar if present

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('.toc').addClass('sticky-nav'); 
            $('.content').css('float','right'); //needs float:right; applied due to .sticky-nav class being positioned
        } else {  
            $('.toc').removeClass('sticky-nav');
            $('.content').css('float','left');
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (stickyEnd - praiseH) ) {
//          $('.toc').addClass('bottom'); removed for fadeIn/fadeOut
            $('.toc').fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('.toc').fadeIn('slow');
        }

    };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();
    });

});
```

Any help on how to de blunk this is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: It seems like jQuery is unable to access the properties of the object `$('.toc')`. Are you sure it exists in the DOM?

Comment: No, in fact it doesn't exist on some pages, but the script is called on every page. Guess I need to target just specific pages with it on, or is there a method for calling it if it only exists?

Comment: You can check if `$('.toc')` exists, and if it does you run the stickyNav function.

Comment: Thanks, Terry. I did just that and it fixed the situation. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `console.log()` function to actually see the native properties of any element.
I don't know if you are limited to JQuery only, but a native JavaScript solution does the trick every time ;)

I found this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop

May be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement to see if my `.toc` element was actually populated and present and now the error goes away and it works on the pages it's supposed to.

Thanks!

```
if ($('.toc').length > 0) { 
    var stickyNavTop = $('.toc').offset().top - 222;
    var stickyEnd = $('.content').height() - 111; // stores height of .content element
    var praiseH = $('.praise').height(); //height of praise bar if present

    var stickyNav = function(){  
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

        //output test heights
//      $("#test").html($(window).scrollTop());
 //   $("#height").html(stickyEnd);
  //  $("#praise").html(footerH);

        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {   
            $('.toc').addClass('sticky-nav'); 
            $('.content').css('float','right'); //needs float:right; applied due to .sticky-nav class being positioned
        } else {  
            $('.toc').removeClass('sticky-nav');
            $('.content').css('float','left');
        }

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= (stickyEnd - praiseH) ) {
//          $('.toc').addClass('bottom'); removed for fadeIn/fadeOut
            $('.toc').fadeOut('slow');
        } else {
            $('.toc').fadeIn('slow');
        }

    };

    stickyNav();

    $(window).scroll(function() {  
        stickyNav();
    });
}
```